# Is there any way I can add the hours and have this timer go off when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this public timer online, only it starts by itself and only has seconds and minutes, I couldn't find a solution to be able to add the hours, and have it start when I click a button. I am neophyte, would someone kindly be able to add these two little things to the code ?
Thank you very much ! :)

**CSS**

```
#seconds {
  font-size: 5em;}

#minutes {
  font-size: 5em;
}
#colon {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label id="minutes">00</label>
<label id="colon">:</label>
<label id="seconds">00</label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
        var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
        var totalSeconds = 0;
        setInterval(setTime, 1000);

        function setTime()
        {
            ++totalSeconds;
            secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
            minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
        }

        function pad(val)
        {
            var valString = val + "";
            if(valString.length < 2)
            {
                return "0" + valString;
            }
            else
            {
                return valString;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: "would someone kindly be able to add these two little things to the code" - Please try to add them yourself, and if you face an issue, please edit your post and add your specific programming question.

Comment: I try many time to use this code, but still don't know how can I add that when timer arrive at 59 mins, increment it on 1 hour

Comment: You can see how it displays the minutes. Have you tried following the same principle to make it display the hour?

Comment: Ps. This has nothing to do with php, the code you've shown is javascript. I've retagged it for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***here you are:***

```js
var houreLabel = document.getElementById("houre");
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes"); 
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds"); 
var totalSeconds = 0; 
function setTime(){
    totalSeconds++;
    var h = Math.floor(totalSeconds/60/60);
    var m = Math.floor((totalSeconds/60)-(h*60));
    var s = Math.floor(totalSeconds-(m*60)-(h*60*60));
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(s); 
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(m);
    houreLabel.innerHTML = pad(h);
} 
function pad(val){ 
    var valString = val+"";
    if(valString.length<2){
        return "0"+valString;
    }else return valString;
}
```

```css
label{
   font-size:5em;
}
button{
   cursor:pointer;
   font-size:2em; 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setInterval(setTime, 1000), this.style.display='none'">Start Timer</button>
<label id="houre">00</label>
<label>:</label>
<label id="minutes">00</label>
<label>:</label>
<label id="seconds">00</label>
```

Comment: Why did you vote negative!? This code works!